# How can I find out if_heapmin() of AIX works

Tags: memory, heap-memory, aix

`I want to reduce the size of heap in AIX. I tried to use _heapmin() in order to do it.
But It doesn't seem to be working. I can't find the amount of decreased heap by using ps command.
Am I using _heapmin() correctly?  Is there any way to check the reduced heap?
I tested it in AIX 6.1 & 7.2

the test code is below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <extension.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p ;
    int i ;
    int size;
    int sum=0;

    size=1024*1024*100;
    p = (char*) malloc(size);
    if(p == NULL )
    {
        printf("error......%d\n", errno);
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(p,0xfe,size);

    //it's not a big deal. I just tried to prevent a compiler optimization just                          in case.
    for(i=0; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        sum += p[i];
    }
    printf("sum=%d\n",sum);

    printf("[A]after malloc,memset\n");
    sleep(20);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    free(p);

    #ifdef _heapmin
    #undef _heapmin
    #endif
    (void)_heapmin();

    printf("[B]after free, _heapmin \n");

    sleep(100);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

```
I compiled it like this
% xlC_r x.cpp -lhm -O0


After that, I ran it.
% ./x
sum=864026624
[A]after malloc,memset
[B]after free, _heapmin


After [A]after malloc,memset, run ps command.
% ps -p 492028 -o vsz,rssize
  VSZ   RSS
103256 103272


After [B]after free, _heapmin, run ps command.
% ps -p 492028 -o vsz,rssize
  VSZ   RSS
103256 103272
```

I checked it by ps command.
After _heapmin, VSZ and RSSIZE showed the same value as before.
There is no difference even if free()&_heapmin() was executed. _heapmin() is supposed to reduce the freed heap as far as I know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try `mallinfo(3)` to get information.